# Rails acts_as_soft_deletable with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with the acts_as_soft_deletable plugin and a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship.

I have a model "Place" which has a couple of Categories (like restaurant, hotel, etc). This means that a table "places_categories" is created in the database, containing two columns "place", and "category".

When I destroy a place, it is placed in the table "deleted_places" by acts_as_soft_deletable. Then I try to restore it and the application crashes because a place cannot exist without categories. The entries in "places_categories" that stored which categories the place belonged to are deleted as the place is deleted.

How can I make sure that "places_categories" does not remove the relations when a place is moved to the "deleted_places" table?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no option to explicitly preserve those entries - you could do something crazy and stupid and just override the delete_sql option to an empty String or somethings thats not going to fail on the "database-side" like so:

```
class Place
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, :delete_sql => "select true"
end
```

This is **untested** ! Just an idea.

You can read about all available options [here](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.8rc1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M004956).